# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\ \infty} {x - \log(e^x + 1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I stumbled upon this $(\infty-\infty)$-type limit today:
$$\lim_{x\to\ \infty} {x - \log(e^x + 1)}$$

I can't seem to be able to solve it; I tried substituting and manipulating in various ways but I still don't understand how to solve it.

Could anyone help?

Comment: You mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}-\log(1+e^{-x})$?

Comment: Hint: $x =\ln (e^x) $ and $\ln (a/b) =\ln (a) - \ln (b) $ when $a, b \gt 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as follows:
$$\lim(x-\ln(e^x+1))=\lim\big(\ln (e^x)-\ln(e^x+1)\big)=\lim\ln{\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}}=\ln\lim\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}=\ln 1 = 0$$

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\ln(e^x+1)=\ln(e^x(1+e^{-x}))$$
$$=\ln(e^x)+\ln(1+e^{-x})$$
$$=x+\ln(1+e^{-x})$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$\log(1+e^x)=x+\log(1+e^{-x})=x+e^{-x}+\mathcal{O}(e^{-2x}) \quad \text{as } x\to\infty$$
so that
$$x-\log(1+e^x)=-e^{-x}+\mathcal{O}(e^{-2x}),$$
implying that the limit is zero.